# setContentView in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm trying to convert a Activity to fragment. The error mark on setContentView.

here is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_googlev2);
    Init();
    addMarkersToMap();
    yStart = 21.102918;
    yEnd = 20.960798;
    xStart = 105.772762;
    xEnd = 105.900650;
    xNow = xStart;
    yNow = yStart;
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    textView.setThreshold(3);
    adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
    textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
            autoCount = count;
            autoS = s;
            if(autoCount % 3 == 1) {
                stCommand = "AutoCompleteTextView";
                lp = new ExecuteTask();
                lp.execute();
            }
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){ // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
        }
    });
}
```

how to convert that setContentView ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shouldn't go in onCreate, you must override onCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {             
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_googlev2, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

bclymer has the correct answer to what you are asking, I just would like to add that you can also take care of `findViewById` inside that method like such:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {             
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_googlev2, container, false);
    textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
    return rootView;
}
```

Also, `onCreateView` is called after `onCreate` so if you try to use `findViewById` in your `onCreate` it will return null since there is no layout view attached yet.